# how to fetch value from json formate wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, post-meta

```
a:1:{s:9:"image_url";a:2:{i:0;s:62:"http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/g4-5.jpg";i:1;s:62:"http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/g1-2.jpg";}}
```

Above is my data. I am using WordPress and I retrieve those data from post meta table. Now I want to show images only. So I want to retrieve image path which is store in above as S:62. I don't know how I can retrieve. please help or guide me to solve my problem.

Comment: It's not a JSON, [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it in PHP first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [maybe_unserialize()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/)

```
$unserialize = maybe_unserialize( $serialize );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not JSON data it's serialized data, if it is related to post meta data then you have to use WordPress function [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

In WordPress, mostly you can find the serialized data in `wp_options`, `wp_postmeta` and `wp_usermeta`. WordPress provides various API to fetch these meta data from DB. (Here the table prefix `wp_` is a configurable prefix so in most WP application you will find random prefix like `df18ef_` this one change in WP DB will increase the security of you web application.)

Don't rely on custom SQL always try to use WP functions to fetch data because they optimize the fetching logic by cache the data in in-memory (especially transient data) object if your setup was configured for object caching then using WP built-in function save you a lot because most plugins used for object caching either using redis or memcache rely on WP provided hooks so instead of using SQL statement use WP functions to get proper data.

Usage:

`$post_meta_1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_meta_key', true );`

Comment: i have used already but i cant get answer. can i send you my source code? i need to solve because it is my college project.

Comment: No problem please share the link of the source code.